# What is the proper HTTP status code to be used when a strategy selection fails server side?

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-codes

Consider a server side procedure to implement an algorithm and an API endpoint used to execute the algorithm on the provided input data.

To fix the idea imagine that the request content describes a travel between two places and that the server side algorithm is used to compute the time needed to complete the travel. Imagine also that many algorithms exist to compute the travel time and that the algorithm selection is somewhat based on the request content (the client calling the API endpoint can specify that he doesn't want to use toll roads or maybe that he wants to use the least busy road possible).

**This scenario is usually coded by using one of the variant of the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)**.

Now image that the API client specifies that he wants to use the most scenic route and that our server side implementation does not include an algorithm to be used for this request (maybe the only available algorithms are "avoid toll roads", "least busy road" and "shortest path"). In this case the server is not able to handle the user request and some sort of error status code must be returned to the client.

Should I consider the server unable to handle the request hence returning a 5XX status code or the client request contaning invalid parameters hence returning a 4XX status code ?

Put another way, is the server unable to handle the request because of server-side issues or is the client sending an invalid / malformed request to the server ?

Comment: There is never a "right" status code to use for web APIs - it is down to whatever you, as the API designer, feel is the most appropriate (including but not limited to defining your own 4xx/5xx status code for this instance). Personally, I would stick with a known 4xx response - perhaps 422 Unprocessable Entity?

Comment: @IanKemp agree with you because we expect to have a complete server side implementation (I mean, all the cases allowed for the business scenario are accounted for) so in case of algorithm selection error it means that the client has asked for a not allowed / envisioned use case, so this is a client error not a server error.

Comment: @IanKemp but I'm not a rest expert and as you noticed in your comment http status codes need some sort of interpretation, they are not deterministic. So i'm asking to people having more experience than me with this kind of tradeoffs and interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Mentionning

> our server side implementation does not include an algorithm to be used for this request

It is client's responsability to use the API with existing "algorithms".
From what I understood of your problem, client doesn't explicitly send a parameter like `?algorithm=ASTAR`.
Only two possibilities remain :

- Server does understand the request but is not able to treat it. `?tollRoads=false` is a valid parameter

  - Is there a fallback ? Can you redirect to any other algorithm ?

    - Yes => `300` you can redirect user to other URLs
    - No => `204`/`501` it's a valid request, but the server can't handle it
- It's not a valid parameter => `400` user should not send such parameter